# Basic concepts video data structure and processing

Tags: hadoop, video

In first sorry for my English. I am not a native speaker. Please be patient.

The video file is a lot of images compressed and played at some predefined rate. Of course this is a simple and brief description. I need to make a distributed application to process a video in a Hadoop cluster to apply video filters. My question is: Is it necessary to uncompress the video in all images and apply the filter to ALL the images or have a method more intelligent to do this to reduce the time to process it?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to add a few examples of the filters you would like to apply first, I am not an expert in video processing, but I believe that it might be an important information for those who can actually answer you question. For example [Deblocking filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deblocking_filter) is applied on compressed video, I believe there are others which applied on per-frame basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to apply grayscale, vintage effects and others like this http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess even an article would be not sufficient to cover the aspects of your task. The way how I managed to resolve similar task was using Storm framework within Hadoop. This service provides a distributed mechanism to stream your data in real time. Each piece of data is processed through workflow called Topology which consists of a set of sources called spouts and units of logic called bolts. So the for your case you can stream video to spout which will then sent it to some filtering bolt. This unit can encapsulate some video processing logic using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library for example. You can use [FrameGrabber](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv/FrameGrabber.java) to parse your video or chunks of video and perform certain filtering steps. Another option would be to integrate usage of [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) directly into Storm bolt. But this would require some extra steps for [generating](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) proper ffmpeg build with necessary codecs for your particular environment. These are to things which you can probably look at for start.